# Why hadoop cmd is still showing error even after setting environment variable

Tags: hadoop

i have installed hadoop and set hadoop_home and bin in path
but i am still getting this error

hadoop -version
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Did you set `JAVA_HOME` to point to JDK location in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by space or special characters in your username or java command path